# Screen size issue with 5-inch, 6-inch phones, wrong layout

Tags: android, format, size, screen

My app works well with phones less than 5" and tablets greater than 7", but the gray area that is between 5" and 7" (phablets) makes problems. In my app, I programmatically check to see if the device is a tablet by the following:

`int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;`

`if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) { 
// for tablets
}`

I use that size check because my app does different things compared to being used on a phone. Likewise I have two versions of the layout of my Activities/Fragments, one for phones and one for tablets. The one for tablets I keep in the values/layout-sw600dp folder while the phone layout is kept in values/layout. Unfortunately, when testing on a 5.4" screen and a 6" screen, the app assigns the device a tablet layout instead of a phone layout because

Is there some way to programmatically check the physical diagonal dimension of the screen size of the device? Specifically for 5" devices?

Comment: have you added <support_screen /> tag in Android Manifest?

Comment: I looked that up and that's if you want to restrict your app to certain screen sizes. I'm trying to appeal to ALL screen sizes, it's just on 5" phones the activities are assigned layouts in the values/layout-sw600dp folder (the tablet layout) instead of in the values/layout folder